# Excessive flex cable wiring for just a normal USB 3.0

Tags: usb, laptop

I was doing a routine check on my laptop, cleaning the fans to check to see if everything was in proper working order. While I was doing this I saw this additional board for a standard USB 3.0 type:

[image: Board back view]
[image: Board front view]

One port had a bunch of lines coming on the ribbon cable. This seemed strange since you dont normally need that many lines, and what also seemed strange is that a chipset and some other components seem to be missing on the board.

I looked around but couldn't find any information about this particular board. Does anyone have any idea of why that amount of lines for that single USB port?

**My laptop:**
ASUS TF-F15 (12 gen i5, RTX 3050 model)

Comment: It is not "for a single port". There is some obvious repetition of component layout intended for a second port on the card and that port and components are simply not fitted. There may well be a version of this board that is used in another laptop that has USB C available or something.

Comment: "that amount of lines" ... how many? do you mean the 9 connections to the USB socket?